# How to find out if Binary Search Tree contains a node given by user

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I would like to create a bool method **bool search(int)** to find out if the BST(Binary Search Tree) contains the node given by user.

**I know this algorithm:**
We start by comparing the number given by user with the number of the BST root. There are three possibilities:
1.given number is equal to the root - the search ends successfully, method returns true
2.given number is greater than the root - then we continue recursively on the right descendant (right subtree)
3.given number is less than the root - then we continue recursively on the left descendant (left subtree)

I know the concept of this problem and how it should work but I still can not write the code that really works. Could you please help me to fix it?

Here is my code (it doesn´t work but I think that the concept is correct):

```
#include <process.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class BinarySearchTree
{
    private:
        struct tree_node
        {
           tree_node* left;
           tree_node* right;
           int data;
        };
        tree_node* root;
    public:
        BinarySearchTree()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }
        void insert(int);
        bool isEmpty() const { return root==NULL; }
        bool search(int);

};

//----------------------------------------------------------
void BinarySearchTree::insert(int d)
{
    tree_node* t = new tree_node;
    tree_node* parent;
    t->data = d;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    parent = NULL;
  // is this a new tree?
  if(isEmpty()) root = t;
  else
  {
    //Note: ALL insertions are as leaf nodes
    tree_node* curr;
    curr = root;
    // Find the Node's parent
    while(curr)
    {
        parent = curr;
        if(t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
        else curr = curr->left;
    }
    if(t->data < parent->data)
       parent->left = t;
    else
       parent->right = t;
  }


}
bool BinarySearchTree::search(int d)
{
    if (d ==  tree_node* root)
        return true;
    else if (d >  tree_node* root)
    {
        if (this->right != NULL)    // case it has right descendant
            this->right->search(d);
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this->left != NULL)     // case it has left descendant
            this->left->search(d);
        else
            return false;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree b;
    int ch,tmp,tmp1;
    while(1)
    {
       cout<<endl<<endl;
       cout<<" Binary Search Tree Operations "<<endl;
       cout<<" ----------------------------- "<<endl;
       cout<<" 1. Insertion/Creation "<<endl;
       cout<<" 2. Does BST contain this number? "<<endl;
       cout<<" 3. Exit "<<endl;
       cout<<" Enter your choice : ";
       cin>>ch;
       switch(ch)
       {
           case 1 : cout<<" Enter Number to be inserted : ";
                    cin>>tmp;
                    b.insert(tmp);
                    break;
           case 2 : cout<<" Enter number to be found : ";
                    cin>>tmp1;
                    b.search(tmp1);
                    break;
           case 3 : system("pause");
                    return 0;
                    break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might wanna check on t->data == d somewhere in your search. Part from that it looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using while loop. Just iterate through proper nodes. If value was found it returns true, else if temp node becomes NULL and value was not found, loop terminates and false is returned.

```
bool BinarySearchTree::search(int d) {
    tree_node* temp = root;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->data == d) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (d > temp->data) {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
            else {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this line of code: `this->right->search(d);` you call some function called `search` from `right` structure. `right` is of type `tree_node`, so there's no function `search` in it, hence the error. I suppose you were trying to make some recursive call to `search` from your class.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (d ==  tree_node* root)
```

Should be changed into

```
if (d == root->data)
```

Comment: So instead of `this` should be `root` ?

Comment: @Anakin Yes. There is no `BinarySearchTree::data`, so you should use `root->data`.

Comment: And also there is a problem concerning `this->right->search(d);` and `this->left->search(d);`, can you tell me how to fix this, should I use some loop or something? I mean that the compiler reports this error: 
`'struct BinarySerachTree::tree_node' has no member 'search'`

Comment: @Anakin Please refer to macfij 's answer.